# Running Jupyter from Excel using VBA

Tags: python, excel, vba

I am trying to run python code in Jupyter notebook using excel macros. It is initializing the python exe but not providing any output or even error.
Any suggestions on what's going on here is much appreciated.

```
Sub CRGOPE_Python_Excel_UI()
Dim objShell As Object
Dim PythonExe, PythonScript As String
    Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
    PythonExe = """C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\python.exe"""
    PythonScript = "C:\Users\daskuma\.ipynb_checkpoints\CRGOPE_Consistency_Algo_v2-checkpoint.ipynb"
    objShell.Run PythonExe & PythonScript
    Application.Goto Reference:="CRGOPE_Python_Excel_UI"
    
End Sub
```